# How to Use two authentications i.e one provided by identity and other manually created in one Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am currently working on a project in which i have used identity for user login/registration system and i have created custom authorization for admin. Both user and admin have different login pages and different tables in database.

Problem is that when i use [Authorize] keyword for some method in user's controller, it redirects me to Admin's authentication (admin login page).

**What i want to do:**

When i use [Authorize] keyword in user's controller it should goes to user login page if the user is not logged in.

when i use [Authorize] keyword in admin's controller it should move me to admin login page if the admin is not logged in.

How can i use [Authorize] keyword?

Your good response can helps me a lot.

Regards.

Comment: You can write the custom `Authorize` attribute (inherited from `Authorize`) to redirect to appropriate login page.

Comment: @user1672994 can you please guide me how to write that class?

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://blog.georgekosmidis.net/2014/05/17/mvc-custom-authorizeattribute-for-custom-authentication/)